# How to replace strings on several columns

Tags: awk

I'm processing large mbox file in order to analyse the mail traffic of info@acme.com. File is already in csv with 11 columns. The number of required replacements is large (>25) and it works just fine with àwk gsub` function. But I just realised that replacement should be performed just on columns $3, $7 and $9 and I would like to find an optimal solution to do it.

CSV file is delimited with ;
Between delimiters newline can appear. Typically newline inside the field is indicated with `?=` at the end of line and `=?` at the begining of the next line, for example this is a headers line, empty line and one row of data:

```
Message-ID;X-GM-THRID;X-Gmail-Labels;X-Google-Original-Date;Date;From;To;Subject;X-Spam-Flag;HasAttachment;AttachmentNames

<01a201d59317$3457d540$9d077fc0$@sbb.us>;1649279601489016232;"=?UTF-8?Q?Archived,Important,Opened,Category_?=
=?UTF-8?Q?Personal,kupci/cb-ac,naro=C4=8Dila-kupcev?=";;Mon, 4 Nov 2019 14:53:14 +0100;<bill.zeit@fgr.us>;=?iso-8859-2?Q?acme_naro=E8ilo?= <info@acme.us>;=?iso-8859-2?Q?NARO=C8ILO_7209661?=;;True;ACME 7096_2019.pdf
```

My task is to clean the data. Specifically, the row above should become:

```
Message-ID;X-GM-THRID;X-Gmail-Labels;X-Google-Original-Date;Date;From;To;Subject;X-Spam-Flag;HasAttachment;AttachmentNames

01a201d59317$3457d540$9d077fc0$@sbb.us;1649279601489016232;Archived,Important,Opened,Category Personal,kupci/cb-ac,naročila-kupcev;;Mon, 4 Nov 2019 14:53:14 +0100;bill.zeit@fgr.us;acme naročilo info@acme.us;NAROČILO 7209661;;True;ACME 7096 2019.pdf
```

Currently I run the command:

`awk -f replacements.awk email.csv > newEmail.csv`

File replacements.awk looks like this:

```
{
  gsub("_"," ");
  gsub("20="," "); 
  gsub("=?","");   
  gsub(/\?=/,"");  
  gsub("_"," ");
  gsub("<","");
  gsub(">","");
  gsub(/"/,"");
  ...
  print
 }
```

I would like to have replacements.awk written in way that I don't need to repeat gsub statements three times in order to replace strings on three columns.

Thanks

Comment: You mentioned substitution should happen only on 3rd, 7th and 9th column but when you use `gsub` and DO NOT mention any field number to it specifically it simply performs substitutions on whole line itself. So could you please confirm if you want to perform substitutions only on 3 fields(3rd, 7th and 9th) once?

Comment: [edit] your question to show concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can help you. See [ask] if that's not clear.

Comment: Initially I was replacing in the whole file, for instance diacritical characters like 'ž' are encoded in a specific way:  `gsub("=C5=BE","ž")` but later I realised 'ž' can be encoded in a shorter way as well: `gsub("C5BE","ž")`. Then I noticed that 'CB5E' could be part of ID-string, which means that I need to replace only on specific columns (fields). Bottom line: Yes, I need to perform substitution only on 3rd, 7th and 9th column (field).

Comment: Fine. See [my earlier comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58800364/how-to-replace-strings-on-several-columns/58801563#comment103882932_58800364) for how to best get help.

Comment: You seem to be doing substitutions one by one. This actually has an important effect. Example, imagine your string to be `foo 2>=30=` will turn due to gsub3 into `foo 2>0=` and due to gsub6 into `foo 20=` which then, if you run it again` would turn into `foo  ` due to gsub2. While if you would run all the substitutions in one go (as is done by the examples), this would turn into `foo 2=`. We need more information to be able to understand what you want.

Comment: You weren't asked to just throw up random "test data" you were asked to provide concise, testable sample input and expected output. We can't see the wood for the trees in the "test data" you posted especially since you didn't provide the expected output for it. Take a minute to actually THINK and come up with a [mcve] including sample input and expected output that demonstrates your requirements including the edge cases where, for example, order of execution of the `gsub()`s matters (if it does).

Comment: And make sure a line in your posted sample is a line in your real data. In your example `<176500287.3597.1572877018895@kvm0356.pdc.us>;1649281093918734667;Inbox,Category Personal,Unread,jn;;Mon,  4 Nov 2019 15:16:58 +0100 (CET);ejn@gov.us;info@acme.us;"Obvestilo glede oddane ponudbe (poziv na dopolnitev) / Notice on` and 
`the submitted tender (call to supplement)";;False;` are 2 separate lines - if that's not true in your real data then don't post it as such in the sample data that we'll be testing a potential solution against.

Comment: It looks like your field separator is a `;` - [edit] your question to state whether or not a `;`, `"`, or newline can appear within a quoted field and include those cases in your sample input/output if they exist.

Comment: The question is edited, the sample data is simplified, I hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like this might be what you want:

```
awk '
BEGIN {
    split("3 7 9", tgts)
}
{
    for (i in tgts) {
        tgt = tgts[i]
        gsub(/_|20=/," ",$tgt)
        gsub(/=\?|\?=|[<>"]/,"",$tgt)
    }
    print
}
' file
```

but without sample input/output it's just an untested guess.

Comment: Be aware that combining the substitutions might lead to different results then having separate substitutions. We do not know if the separate substitutions in the original problem were intended or not.

Comment: Right, as I mentioned `without sample input/output it's just an untested guess`

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't shown samples of your Input_file and expected output so couldn't test it. You have multiple Global substitutions which either substitute a regex/string to a space OR to NULL, so we can club both.

I have clubbed all regex for space together and all regex for NULL together as follows.

```
gsub(/_|20=/," ");gsub(/=\?|\\\?=|<|>|\"/,"")
```

You could use `|`(OR) for mentioning multiple regexp in `gsub`. I had taken all regexp from your shown samples, if you have some more then you could club them like I have done above too.

---

---

***EDIT:*** Adding an example to remove perform multiple `gsub` operations on multiple fields, lets say following is the Input_file. This is just an example you need to adjust it as per your Input_file.

```
cat Input_file
1 23_?=??": bla bla bla
1 23_?=??": bla bla bla
1 23_?=??": bla bla bla
1 23_?=??": bla bla bla
1 23_?=??": bla bla bla
1 23_?=??": bla bla bla
1 23_?=??": bla bla bla
```

Now following is the solution.

```
awk '
function remove(field){
  num=split(field,array,",")
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    gsub(/=\?|\\\?=|<|>|\"/,"",$i)
  }
}
remove("2,3")
1
' Input_file
```

In above I mentioned `remove("2,3")` which means I am calling function named `remove` and `2,3` means perform `gsub` operation on 2nd and 3rd fields, but this is only an example of substitution only, you need to adjust it in your code or you could take it as a starting step.

Comment: Be aware that combining the substitutions might lead to different results then having separate substitutions. We do not know if the separate substitutions in the original problem were intended or not.

Answer (score 1):

- consolidate multiple replacement patterns into a single combination using either regex *alternation group* `..|..` or *character class* `[...]`
- move common substitutions to a custom function that will accept a column as an argument

---

```
function sub_col(col) {
    gsub(/[<>"]|\?=|=\?/, "", $col);
    gsub(/_|20=/, " ", $col);
}
{
    sub_col(3); sub_col(7); sub_col(9);  
}
```

Comment: Be aware that combining the substitutions might lead to different results then having separate substitutions. We do not know if the separate substitutions in the original problem were intended or not.